# Riddle 'n Rhymes

Tags: riddle

with these Devilish Devices to firmly in hanD,
DetermineD heroes make their stanD together,
Despite the oDDs being quite misconstrueD, 
the games of chance they live their lives by
have DeemeD their Doom imminently DeriveD
evil lives Despite their meDDling
and away their heaDs rolleD

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you:

> Are you a Dice? specifically D20s.

Old Answer and reasoning:

> The game Dungeons & Dragons AKA D&D. Thought this because of the highlighting of the letter 'D', the references to chance, talk of heroes, etc. Also as pointed out by @Excited Raichu there are 20 uppercase Ds in the text and the main die used in Dungeons and Dragons is a D20.

Comment: Also, rot13(gurer ner gjragl qf hccrepnfrq, naq gur znva qvr bs gur tnzr vf gjragl fvqrq)

Comment: You are so very close. rot13(jvgu gurfr qrivyvfu qrivprf) is the crux of the puzzle

Comment: @gabbo1092 - probably rot13(gur qvpr)?

Comment: I will have to make these harder in the future. The answer is yours! However you missed a small hint via the title!